# How to push value in array inside array that is in state

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, datatable, treeview

I have values that I am pushing into array and showing in table. This `formValues` have children key with value of array in order to make a tree view inside table. Now my question is how can I push same values inside children array from different state?

These are values I am pushing into the database and fetching to show in the table:

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    note: "",
    module: "",
    status: statusData[0].key,
    children: [],
    key: uniqueKey(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in case someone will need it..

```
const handleSubmit = (item) => {
     const val = item;
  setFormValues((prev) => ({...prev ,children:[...prev.children , val]}));
}
handleSubmit(/*values from other state*/)
```